# Error: Could not find or load main class Game.GUI.Start Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

Tags: java, maven, javafx, build, pom.xml

I'm new to maven and am having issues. I have a JavaFx app but I keep getting the error in the title. I have tried many different versions of the POM but can't get it to work. Here is the POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>Coursework2013</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
        <javafx.version>19</javafx.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>Snake.GUI.Start</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javazoom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jlayer</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and the start of Start (as I'm guessing thats related):

```
package Snake.GUI;

import Snake.GUI.controller.DataHandler;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
public class Start extends Application {
```

I tried many different ways of telling it where main was and all that, but it didn't help. I've looked at many similar issues but their questions on stack but their solutions have not worked for me. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I recommend following the suggestion in mipa's answer and following the documentation he linked to use the maven javafx plugin to create a jlinked zip file for your distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Do not blindly follow any obscure recomendations. Start with the official documentation that you can find here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven
You do not have to copy any dependencies into some build folder.